# How to add a login to the dbcreator role?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, role

Using SSMS, I'm having trouble adding a new login to the server `dbcreator` role on my Azure SQL instance.

Here's the syntax I'm using:

```
CREATE LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD = 'SuperSecret!'
ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [test]
```

This works fine on a local SQL instance, but in Azure it fails with

> Cannot alter the server role 'dbcreator', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I've verified that I'm connected to the server using the Server Admin Login credentials, but the problem persists. Internet searches only turn up the above T-SQL code.

How can I add a login to the `dbcreator` role in Azure SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dbcreator` role doesn't exist in an Azure SQL Database because there are no server level roles in the Azure SQL Database product.

You can find which types of Microsoft database products do support it on the [Server-Level Roles documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15). It appears to just be SQL Server and Parallel Data Warehouse.

For further information on provisioning administrative capabilities in Azure SQL Database, please see [Create additional logins and users having administrative permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage#create-additional-logins-and-users-having-administrative-permissions).

Additionally, it does seem despite there not being *traditional* server level roles in Azure SQL Database, there are two dedicated roles that exist in the `master` database only, to mimic similar behavior. `dbmanager` is one of them, and is used to provision `CREATE DATABASE` permissions to a **User**. Please see the docs on this in [Special Roles for SQL Database and Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15#special-roles-for--and-azure-synapse). This may be what you're looking for, as you won't have to provide `sysadmin` privileges then.

Comment: Hm, this could be problematic. I want this login to be able to create databases, but I don't want it to be a sysadmin. Will this be possible?

Comment: In the docs you linked (thank you), this statement seems self-contradictory for the first SQL Database step: "Create an additional SQL login in the master database." Aren't logins by definition at the server level, not at the database level?

Comment: @InteXX Please see my last update to my answer, as I think I've found a way that might be what you're looking for. Regarding your second question, I'm unsure if that is a typo by Microsoft, or is accurate in those special cases, but neither apply to Azure SQL Database anyway.

Comment: My testing results in SSMS just now are somewhat disappointing. I was able to add the database under the new user, after issuing `ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER test`. So that part works. Unfortunately, however, at least for my case (I'm using Entity Framework Code First Migrations), the login isn't added to the new database as the `dbo` user, as it is under [on-prem MSSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlacJ.png). In fact, no user is added to the new database at all. Consequently, when using Migrations under Azure SQL, the new database is created but the login can't access anything within it.

Comment: So this means we have two options: 1) Use the sysadmin login for normal read/write operations, or 2) Create the database and configure security manually using SSMS. Option #2 seems the more sane approach. Fortunately, in my case at least, my web app architecture doesn't call for databases to be created on the fly. Migrations will detect that the database already exists and skip to the schema updates. It certainly won't be the end of the world.

Comment: I'm trying this again today, but I'm running into an error: `Cannot add the server principal 'test', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.` It can't be a permissions issue, as I'm logged in as sysadmin. The login does indeed exist. What do you make of it?

Comment: @InteXX What query did you run to get that error?

Comment: Oh man, I created a hot mess with this one. First, I forgot to update you with the results. Then I got it working, but not before I falsely accused the documentation team of [publishing conflicting rules](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7502). In the end, [this solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/311201/63237) worked. I can now create a new database with the authenticated user as `dbo`. Which is what I've been after all this time. Finally. Ugh.

Comment: Everybody kept saying **user**, and for some reason all I could see was **login**. It's my parents' fault. They gave me mental blocks for Christmas.

Comment: And it turns out there's a catch with this approach! When you let your app create the database, instead of doing it manually via the portal, the default pricing tier is **Gen5/2Core**. I didn't notice it for two weeks and I managed to rack up two hundred bux in unnecessary charges. Advice: don't do that 